# Why can't typescript infer return type in compose type

Tags: typescript

I have a pick function which picks attributes from an object. Obviously I want the return type to reflect the new type that is generated.

```
const getIdentifier = pick(['type', 'id'])
const result = getIdentifier(record)

// works as expected
const id = result.id
// is missing as expected
const name = result.attributes.name
```

But as soon I use the function in a compose type function, it doesnt infer its type anymore:

```
const run = compose(
    // doesnt infer type, id constrain, why not???
    (identifier) => identifier,
    getIdentifier,
    // infers RecordJson
    (rec) => rec,
    getRecord
)
```

See full types and examples at [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.0-beta#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVzRAW0gGdgAeAFQEYA+ACgRQAYAuOOgSjgF4a5qObTjz7UA3AFgAUKEixEqDNlz4iEUmQBqTADT9aDZkJCs42rr32D2JtuZH7JU6bOjxk6LDjyES5anoUAEz0jFTGbAIOwXqMpsKWAkIWokFOrvIeSt6qflq6+oEhhuE2kVQp-EGxRjam9okVxvVMlcFOLuBuCp7KPmoaAVWBAMz00nCIKEERVW0jOhNTpXQg5W3VS3HJ0VTS1gmiI+ldmYpeKr7q5NqBVEWj41KTjDNlc9ELWygra1bRm2eU3ifwaoj2UgOoNanw6MlO7nOfVy10o92G-AW-AALE8XigRrMKCM2tjFkDXkSgvNyfjfusAbTgTtGvsWaJsSc5IjejkrhpboUMcTAri6N9Ce9iaSmZSpdTPrKfkSKozviC7DDWZDZmCcXCMjzspcBv50TFMaLAgBWPFTbFE7Fta1KyWrSIk6Jk75vd0fRJfCnKqWqxKA-HxNoQg7OrndLIXfp5QVDC0inE2u2MB1Sp3RF0SomexLeoO+v7BGnfen-MNKjVmLXgtnvPUUa0GhE9Y1J1Gp6qWjP8F38ABsWZQ1qJ1rao6VOb9FDziQLQbdFeLHKV5ciCoDSprUTr6vZ+hbhzHcbOvJNyYK-dGVuHgXH4qDU6lM+ic++C4ry9EVd8XXD0ZR9KkqyDQ9Q1SetdSbM8dVbBCKFHTtuW7RMUVIdgwCgCAwGINgAEMUAAT2sUiyLgABvABfaROgwhM+jATA0AAa0oPQAGk4FAGBgBQAATYg4GIGAoEwFAAHM4AAHzgFAkAIAAjYAoAU8SyLUiAABt6BQYiCGAIi4CgYBiOEnA9OoniAG0AF09AgVSACtImsAAFdiuIoPQAFEQDQPSkGE8gOOAMiIAQfhAuC0LwrISLoti-y4B4mgsqvI1EzYziyD4gShNE8TJOkuTFOUtSNK04gdNU-TDOM0y2AsqybLspzrEoehXI8-hKh8gr0qCkKwoiqKYriuAxsSybUpmzKsqY+MkW8fKONw-DCJI8jKPI2iGOcKQYDIsBgDgAAlYB8CgYSACliG8bhaLgM6LrYCSpNksQ4EwYSvvK364GImBytUpBBLMmilJaoGfrkui4GO6R8BQCTzNu6BhJ4I7QbEm67se56UEYqR0cxmTgBgImcbxi8LOJ8nKfgamYAASXClAsAQTBateza6HsgByD7gBFvQRYBkXHI4NGcExiziCQPT4Fe9muaE3n+agOgmZx+WToAemNuAAHdoA4sTiLE2RbsE4SFYx+AAbx5XVZgAA6AHpFN-6xIITBiGICqCf48AHeAJ2KcV+AjJM93TM9r2wYhqHTK9hPgBZuPzNQPHsOAN9Jkmf3rNMnn-pQBBavFvQ3dZqBiOkvRzYAC2olAIBgAB+fulkmOgAe1zA+Y0yoR55sfdaZSZNe5nWNLnuB-ek2uoEJ7H7qenBB-YJnKiZlf2bp+79mkIA).

Is TypesScript unable to do this? Will it ever be able to? Is there any way for me to get this to work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can check my article about typing compose function https://catchts.com/FP-style#compose

Comment: consider using TS 4.5 for this approach, it allows you to handle more than 10 functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typescript doesn't like it when it has to resolve generics by looking at the last argument to a function first, it looks at the first argument, can't figure out the generics so sets it to `unknown` then continues with that and doesn't backtrack.

if you write your `compose` as a pipeline instead of composition of functions it works:

```
declare function composeA<Initial, A,B, Final>(f1: (a:Initial)=>A, f2: (b:A)=>B, f3: (c: B)=>Final): Final

interface A{
  a:{
    id: string,
    name: string,
    other: number
  }
}

declare function pick_id_and_name<T extends Record<"id"|"name", unknown>>(val:T): Pick<T, "id"|"name">
// this works perfectly
const getField = composeA(
  (data: A)=>data.a,
  pick_id_and_name,
  (stuff)=>[stuff.id, stuff.name]
)

declare function composeB<Initial, A,B, Final>(f3: (c: B)=>Final, f2: (b:A)=>B, f1: (a:Initial)=>A): Final
// this falls into the same error you are getting, `stuff` is unknown
const getField2 = composeB(
  (stuff)=>[stuff.id, stuff.name],
  pick_id_and_name,
  (data: A)=>data.a,
)
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.0-beta#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXzBwFsAHHAZxAEEAeASVS2yggBp4rWAhdgMS1QsAfAApEARgBc8EVEkMmWFgEoAvEM5IATNJEAjSVTVCeSAMy6w0rsf6CIy6XZYBYAFDuBGEDERQwCFQA3u7w8HIhbmFhWMDS5BgwAgDmrKHRgkQg8YkpaVHROBgAFj7SqMhEej7pAL7u9R5uoJCwCCjo2HjwJFhgANYA+rGDUKjAg5kgNAAq8CAAHt7j5PAASuA4MMA0AESxuwA+u1O77Gj9qDgA7qhCogBuLJIzjvAACn39s+z7wEcnKBZXZCdzuQioBLwZIgDD8EAQYDwVQEYhkShUETpETAKAYOQcYy4-EAOig+TCvQGwwmYwmUwpMgSyEQiGMAG1maySbF2FzECSpgBddzKMHNcDQOBINCYXD4QikCggLj0RjMNgcbh8ATCMQWGRWeA2dTOTWIHQyAxGdSmCS6OQKDXGIxOXUQcF4KEwuFYBHALTI1FKyhcLEFET8jn8nnAPkYFkC4WMqlDEZ0yZAkCMnF4gk2oTEqBk-LKIA)